# R: Lattice Plots/Wireframe : Graphical Issues with labels

Tags: r, lattice

I have a question concerning some graphical options of wireframe.  How can I  make the xlab and the ylab parallel to the cube -  they look horrible in my plots, see for my other post

[Faceted Lattice Plots in R, e.g., wireframes: How to remove strips and add 1-Line subtitles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055745/faceted-lattice-plots-in-r-i-e-wireframes-how-remove-stripes-and-add-1-line/30056035#30056035).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass lists to the `zlab`, `xlab` and `ylab` arguments of `wireframe`. One component of these lists can be `rot`, which specifies in degrees the amount by which axis labels should be rotated. So far, I have only been able to "align" the labels with the axes by trial and error.

```
## Code from your other post, to make this reproducible
model_test <- lm(Sepal.Length ~( Petal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Width +Species)^2,
    data=iris)
gg<-expand.grid(Petal.Length=0:6,Species=levels(iris$Species))
vv<-expand.grid(Sepal.Width=0:4,Petal.Width=1:4)

pd<-do.call(rbind,Map(function(Petal.Length,Species,Sepal.Width,Petal.Width){
              nd <- cbind(vv, Petal.Length=Petal.Length,Species=Species,
                               Sepal.Width=Sepal.Width, Petal.Width=Petal.Width)
              cbind(nd, pred=predict(model_test, nd, type="response"))},
              Petal.Length=iris$Petal.Length,Species=iris$Species,
               Sepal.Width=iris$Sepal.Width,Petal.Width=iris$Petal.Width))

## Plot with rotated axis labels
wireframe(pred~Sepal.Width+Petal.Width|Species*Petal.Length,
           pd, drape=FALSE,scale=list(arrows=FALSE),subset=(Species=="setosa"),
           layout = c(3, 3), zlab = list("pred", rot = 90),
           xlab = list("Sepal.Width", rot = 30),
           ylab = list("Petal.Width", rot = -30))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very good! However,  I see that at the Petal.Width axis there are two rows of ticks, how can I remove the "wrong" ticks?

Comment: I think there's a single row of ticks, but the labels are plotted with one digit after the decimal place. Because they're so cramped, they line up so that it looks like two rows. A hack would be to include `at = unique(round(pretty(pd$Petal.Width)))` in your `scales` list. A more thorough approach is outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12374622/1281189